# centos 7 kickstart - forcing single partition

Tags: linux, centos7, partitioning

How can I force a single partition in cents 7 through the kickstart file?

Sometimes disk size is small (virtual box builder, 50GB) sometimes large (v-sphere builder 1TB) how can I ensure that only a single partition is created for both cases?

The regular `autopart` will create multiple partitions.

The full kickstart file can be found here https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/e4944088c5350835672279ec3e7edd0b the (as far as I think relevant subparts (of me trying  to achieve the goal as outlined) are:

```
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda
# Make the volgroup
volgroup VolGroup --pesize=4096 pv.008002

# Setup swap on the volgroup
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=VolGroup --size=2016 --maxsize=2016

# Make / on the volgroup
logvol /  --name=lv_root --vgname=VolGroup --fstype=ext4 --grow --size=1

# Setup the boot partition on the volgroup
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
```

Currently, it does not work and not enough space is assigned for the partition when using the packer script of https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/centos/centos-7.4-x86_64.json with my modified kickstart file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the solution is

```
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel

# cant use autopart require one single big partition
part pv.008002 --size=1 --grow --ondisk=sda
volgroup VolGroup --pesize=4096 pv.008002
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=VolGroup --size=2016 --maxsize=2016
logvol /  --name=lv_root --vgname=VolGroup --fstype=ext4 --grow --size=1
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
```

Comment: The order of these lines is critical. If any of them is out of order, installer goes *splat*

Comment: thanks for this, it helped me get past the lack of --nohome in CentOS7.6 https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13969

Answer (score -1):

autopart has the option to pass no home

```sh
autopart --nohome
```

but it will leave a lot of unassigned space in your volume group if you have a very large disk. You can always do an online resize after the build if you find / to be too small